# Problem with waitable timers in Windows (timeSetEvent and CreateTimerQueueTimer)

Tags: c#, timer

I need high-resolution (more accurate than 1 millisecond) timing in my application.  The waitable timers in Windows are (or can be made) accurate to the millisecond, but if I need a precise periodicity of, say, 35.7142857141 milliseconds, even a waitable timer with a 36 ms period will drift out of sync quickly.

My "solution" to this problem (in ironic quotes because it's not working quite right) is to use a series of one-shot timers where I use the expiration of each timer to call the next timer.  Normally a process like this would be subject to cumulative error over time, but in each timer callback I check the current time (with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`) and use this to calculate what the period of the next timer needs to be (so if a timer happens to expire a little late, the next timer will automagically have a shorter period to compensate).

This works as expected, except that after maybe 10-15 seconds the timer system seems to get bogged down, and a few timer callbacks here and there arrive anywhere from 25 to 100 milliseconds late.  After a couple of seconds the problem goes away and everything runs smoothly again for 10-15 seconds, and then the stuttering again.

Since I'm using `Stopwatch` to set each timer period, I'm also using it to monitor the arrival times of each timer callback.  During the smooth-running periods, most (maybe 95%) of the intervals are either 35 or 36 milliseconds, and no intervals are ever more than 5 milliseconds away from the expected 35.7142857143.

During the "glitchy" stretches, the distribution of intervals is very nearly identical, except that a very small number are unusually large (a couple more than 60 ms and one or two longer than 100 ms during maybe a 3-second stretch).  This stuttering is very noticeable, and it's what I'm trying to fix, if possible.

For the high-resolution timer, I was using the extremely antique `timeSetEvent()` multimedia timer from `winmm.dll`.  In pursuit of this problem, I switched to using `CreateTimerQueueTimer` (along with `timeBeginPeriod` to set the high-resolution), but I'm seeing the same problem with both timer mechanisms.  I've tried experimenting with the various flags for `CreateTimerQueueTimer` which determine which thread the timer runs on, but the stuttering appears no matter what.

Is this just a fundamental problem with using timers in this way (i.e. using each one-shot timer to call the next)?  If so, do I have any alternatives?  One thing I was considering was to determine how many consecutive 1-millisecond-accuracy ticks would keep my within some arbitrary precision limit before I need to reset the timer.  So, for example, if I wanted a 35.71428 period, I could let a 36 ms timer elapse 15 times before it was off by 5 milliseconds, then kill it and start a new one.

Comment: You need a realtime OS! How is this holding up under (heavy) disk activity?

Comment: @Henk: it stutters under heavy disk activity, but then so does playback of *anything* on my computer (video, music etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given limitations in .NET, I think you have a good approach.  What is your process priority?  I'm thinking it needs to be higher than normal to avoid other processes doing disk activity.

I agree with Henk that the .NET framework is not the best solution here.  If garbage collection occurs, it may take a while to free objects, compact the heap, etc.

What OS are you using?  I also agree with Henk that a real-time OS is the best solution.  According to what I've read, Windows CE qualifies as a real-time OS, but I can't really comment further.

Comment: Your answer got me thinking. I was setting the timer thread's priority, but I wasn't doing anything about my process' priority. In .Net, you can set your current process' `PriorityClass`, but when I set it to `AboveNormal`, `High` or `Realtime`, it made my problem massively worse - *all* the timer callbacks end up delayed by 50-100 ms. Counterintuitive, to say the least. Fortunately, the Process class also has a `PriorityBoostEnabled` property which temporarily boosts the process priority when the main window has the focus. Setting this to `true` appears to fix my problem.

Comment: My only guess about the priority class is that maybe upping your own process' priority places it above the priority of the timer mechanism itself, which means your own app is alertly waiting for now much-delayed timer events.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon - problem is still there. Sometimes the problem just goes away for awhile, which makes me think I've fixed it when i haven't.

Comment: That is interesting.  You might want to see how your application behaves when .NET performs a GC.  You can get some control over this process using the Garbage Collection Notifications http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx.  You can also simulate some memory pressure using `GC.AddMemoryPressure()`.

Comment: I think you're right and I will try to see what effect the GC has on this. I understand now why upping the process priority doesn't work - the lower-priority timer process isn't allowed to "bother" my higher-priority app process, so the callbacks get delayed. I think I actually need to boost the timer's priority instead.

Answer (score 1):

Timers aren't cheap and by using a 1ms timer to approach a 35.7 one you are eating away at your margins here. I think you may be at the limit of what can be achieved on the PC itself.
I would go for a longer period timer (35 or 36) and correction with the stopwatch timer.

And to start some controversy, I'm not so sure the .NET framework is the most suitable platform for this kind of task. Have you thought of how the GC fits in with your demands?

Comment: @Henk: I may have mis-explained this, but I *am* using longer period (one-shot) timers of around 35 to 36 milliseconds. The 1 ms is just the *resolution* of the timer, not its period.

Comment: Also, the main advantage that the .NET framework has in this situation is that it's the language the application is already written in. We'll call this "the incumbency advantage". :)